# jRuby on Rails can't connect to db on Amazon EB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jrubyonrails

Yesterday I wanted to try Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, so I created a Java environment, with an RDS (postgres) instance. 
I packaged my simple CMS app using warbler into a war file, uploaded it, but rails outputs the usual "Something went wrong" message.
I checked the logs, and it seems to be a db connection error.
I have these settings in my database.yml file:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: you'll need to provide some more information about your setup in order to troubleshoot this. What's the exact error message? Did you create your RDS as part of the EB wizard? are you using VPC?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using ActiveRecord-JDBC-Adapter and the DB is Amazon's customized PostgreSQL, than unfortunately there are incompatibility issues as it is not tested against "old" PG 8.0 nor against Redshift itself ... see https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/403

users seems to be trying it out but unfortunately none decided to fix AR-JDBC compatibility issues (which should not be hard) ... yet